# Are private fields in a global instance thread safe

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a class of the following shape

```
TParser = class

private

  FFlag : boolean;
  FIntermediateValue : double;

  procedure F1(var aPartOfInput : string);
  procedure F2(var aSmallerPartOfInput : string) ;

public
  function Parse(const anInput : string): double;

end;

function TParser.Parse(const anInput : string) : double;
var
  aPartOfInput : string;
begin

  { Do some checks on the input and set FFlag to true/false.
    Set aPartOfInput to a piece of the input}
  f1(aPartOfInput);
  Result := FIntermediateValue;
end;

procedure TParser.F1(var aPartOfInput : string);
begin
  { Slice some more off the input.
    Set the FIntermediateValue }
  f2(aPartOfInput)
end;

procedure TParser.F2(var aSmallerPartOfInput : string);
begin
  { Depending on the input and FFlag, update FIntermediateValue }
end;
```

We currently create/destroy a squillion (technical term) of these through the system.

I am looking at creating a single instance and invoking it from each of these places.

This single instance will be invoked from multiple threads. 
Does the use of the private fields mean that this is not thread safe?

If this is not thread safe, what are my options for making it thread safe?

**EDIT - Options**

Thanks all for the comments.

*A separate instance for each thread*

Sounds good, but because of the way that the code is structured, the instance would need to be 'global' to the thread, there is no way (as far as I can see) to inject the instance down the object graph to where is it needed (at the moment, new instances of the parser are created where they are needed)

```
threadvar
    TheParser : TParser;
```

seems to be a way to give me this.  Create the instance when we start the thread and free it on leaving.  Are there any problems with this?

*Get rid of the instance variables*

If we re-design the parser so that it is a function rather than an instance of a class and all the values are passed around, would this make it thread safe?

```
interface

function Parse(const anInput : string): double;

implementation

function F2(var aSmallerPartOfInput : string; theFlag : boolean; theIntermediateValue : double) : double ;
begin
  { update theIntermediateValue based on flag and input }
  Result := theIntermediateValue;
end;

function F1(var aPartOfInput : string; theFlag : boolean) : double;
var
  anIntermediateValue : double;
begin
  { Slice some more off the input
    Set the FIntermediateValue }
  Result := f2(aPartOfInput, theFlag, anIntermediateValue)
end;

function Parse(const anInput : string) : double;
var
  aPartOfInput : string;
  aFlag : boolean;
begin

  { set aFlag
    set aPartOfInput to a piece of the input }
  Result := f1(aPartOfInput, aFlag);
end;
```

Comment: Define thread safe? There is too little context in above code, but if there are different threads accessing private fields (reading and writing) even though they are doing this through object instance then this code is not thread safe. [What is thread safety anyway?](https://dalijap.blogspot.com/2017/12/is-it-thread-safe-assume-not.html)

Comment: Everything will be invoking the public `Parse()` function, nothing working behind the scenes.  I am concerned that say, on thread 1 we invoke `Parse()` and FFlag is set to true, then on thread 2 we invoke `Parse()` and FFlag is set to false, then back on thread 1 `F2()`  uses the false value.  I don't know enough to know is this a possiblity

Comment: You need to serialize the access to `Parse`.

Comment: ...or create a separate parser instance per thread...

Comment: The easiest way to make something to be threadsafe is to have distinct instances for each thread of execution. The single global instance is basically the enemy of thread safety.

Comment: I don't know if there is more code but the entire class looks pointless because what it does can be solved with routines and passing the 2 values (intermediate value and flag) to sub routine calls. It should not have any state but use local variables for the Parse call - that will make it threadsafe because as you previously commented currently it is not and very prone to race conditions.

Comment: @ Stefan Glienke  Agreed. The code here is simplified - there are about half a dozen levels and a number of variables that are used to manage state. This is old code with no spec. and pretty convoluted at times. I would rather not re-implement it but if we have no simpler options for a thread safe version then we will.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly. You have a class that is intended to do some processing and now you want to use this class from multiple threads but you fear that it multiple threads are accesing this class whi has private fields one thread would interfere with other. That is true. What you can do is moe this class functionality directly into your thread class. this way the private fields of this class Will actually become private fields of your thread. And since each thread instance is accesing its own fields you easily achieve thread safety. ...

Comment: ... So unless this class is doing something else that isn't thread safe and that we can't see from your posted code I think that task of moving functionality from this clas directly into a thread would be quite easy.

Comment: @SilverWarior - sort of.  The shape is, we have a `Processor` class that opens up a file and does things with it and spits out a result.  We can have a lot of these files so we decided to use the Omnithread library to process them in parallel.  Deep inside the 'Processor'  we use (in lots of places) the TParser. Currently we create a new instance, use it, destroy it.  I would like a single instance (per thread) that we re-use but the problem is then how to get refer to that instance - the `Processor` and `Parser` don't know about the threads. is `threadvar` the way to go?

Comment: If you have a single instance that is going to be used by multiple threads, then *No*, those variables are not thread safe. There is one instance of those variables. You're going to need to implement a locking mechanism. The example of *thread1 we invoke Parse() and FFlag is set to true, then on thread2 we invoke Parse and FFlag is set to false* is clearly the case when you have a single instance of the object being shared by multiple threads - what would you think would prevent that from happening without locking of some sort?

Comment: @KenWhite - didn't think it was thread safe, trying to get external support for my position (and looking for solutions that are thread safe)

Comment: If you already knew it wasn't thread safe, then why does your title ask if it is, instead of asking the question you really wanted to ask (a way to do what you want in a way that is thread safe)?

Comment: You should subclass TOmniWorker class so that you can add field of TParser type to it and then override the Initialize function so that you can create new instance of your TParser class which will then be bound to that TOmniWorker instance. Then in your program you can create as many TOmniWorkers and each will have its own TParser instance created. Oh don't forget to also override Finalize where you will free your TParser class in order to prevent memory leaks that you would cause othervise. I apologize for not writing a code example but its been a while since I used OmniThread library

Answer (score -1):

No, they aren't.

You must synchronize the access, if you want to use the same object instance within different threads.

On Windows just use a critical section (TRTLCriticalSection) and on posix os' use mutex (pthread_mutex_t)

You always can choose to design your class idempotent, so you can have a instance of it in each thread and just use it in there.